# Gradle: run task only if folder exists

Tags: gradle

I've a Java application which has a web component. I am trying to skip running of `npm install` if the `node_modules` folder already exists:

```
tasks.register<NpmTask>("appNpmInstall") {
    onlyIf { !file("node_modules").exists() }
    description = "Installs all dependencies from package.json"
    workingDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/webapp")
    args = listOf("install")
}
```

However, with this configuration, the task still runs. How do I skip the task if `node_modules` exists?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this exact issue, here is the Exec task implementation I ended up writing for my modules build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
open class NpmInstallTask  @Inject constructor(
  objectFactory: ObjectFactory
) : Exec() {

  @get:InputFile
  @get:PathSensitive(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)
  val packageJson = objectFactory.fileProperty()

  @get:OutputDirectory
  val npmModule = objectFactory.directoryProperty()

  @get:OutputFile
  val packageLockJson = objectFactory.fileProperty()

  init {
    commandLine = arrayListOf("npm", "install")
  }
}

val npmInstall = tasks.register<NpmInstallTask>("npmInstall") {
  packageJson.set(layout.projectDirectory.file("package.json"))
  npmModule.set(layout.projectDirectory.dir("node_modules"))
  packageLockJson.set(layout.projectDirectory.file("package-lock.json"))
}

// The build task name may depend on your projects setup, please update accordingly 
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(npmInstall)
```

Now, if node_module does not exist or the package.json has changed since the last time the task ran, then it will execute again. If the node_module does exist or package.json has not changed since the last run. If you add `--info` when running the task, then you should see something like if the task was skipped due to be up-to-date.

```bash
> Task :web:npmInstall UP-TO-DATE
Build cache key for task ':web:npmInstall' is 9fa2ecfdb23584a3i04f0c760e8e34d0
Skipping task ':web:npmInstall' as it is up-to-date.
```